# Declaring a global variable without a value in go

Tags: variables, go, global

I have a program that requires either 1 or 2 arguments depending on what the users wants to run

```
var (
   clientSet = tools.NewClientSet(os.Args[2])
)
func main {
    if os.Args[1] == "validate" {
       // run validate function, no need for user to have os.Args[2]
    }else if os.Args[1] == "sync" {
      // run sync function that requires os.Args[2]
    }
}
func foo{
   tools.Manage(clientSet)
}
```

I need the `clientSet` variable to be global, but I dont need the users to have os.Args[2] if the users only wants to use the validate function. Putting the `clientSet` function inside `main()` will make my `foo()` function broken and I can't declare a variable with an empty value.

So I want my users to be able to run `go run main.go validate` and `go run main.go sync production` smoothly.

*production is an arbitrary value

I could have my users to run `go run main.go validate _` to plug this problem, but that would be inelegant.What's the best way to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't even see the need for a global variable in this case. You can just make the sync function accept a `ClientSet` e.g. `func sync(c ClientSet)`. But if you really need the global variable then you should not do this unless you want your program to panic when there are no arguments present.

```
var (
   clientSet = tools.NewClientSet(os.Args[2])
)
```

What you should do is to assign it a default value or the zero value of your type.

```
var (
   clientSet tools.ClientSet
)
```

Your main function would look somewhat like this:

```
var (
    clientSet tools.ClientSet
)

func main() {

    if len(os.Args) < 2 {
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    switch os.Args[1] {
    case "validate":
        validate()

    case "sync":

        if len(os.Args) < 3 {
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        clientSet = tools.NewClientSet(os.Args[2])
        sync()
    default:
        // place your default case here
    }

}
```

Still, I suggest you just pass a `ClientSet` to the sync function since it will avoid global variables.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is often to not use globals. Instead have `foo` take an argument `foo(clientSet ClientSet)` and instantiate it only if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **len(os.Args)** function

```
var (
    clientSet tools.ClientSet
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Agrs) == 1 {
        // just the file name
    } else if len(os.Args) == 2 {
        if os.Args[1] == "validate" {
            // run validate function, no need for user to have os.Args[2]
        } else if os.Args[1] == "sync" {
            // sync with no argument show error
        }
    } else if len(os.Args) == 3 {
        if os.Args[1] == "validate" {
            clientSet = tools.NewClientSet(os.Args[2])
        } else {
            // non validate with the second arg
        }
    } else {
        // else, if required
    }
}
```

Atlhough I would suggest you to NOT to use global variables. Avoid if possible.